# Reuse templated variables in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a group of ansible tasks that require a common list of variables.
The problem of such list is that it requires certain customization per task.
The common block is a list of labels for a docker container (so they are discovered by traefik).
I can put the list of labels inside a variable on the `vars` section of the playbook, but It will be evaluated just once, and I want it to be re-evaluated per task with new set of variables.

This is the list of labels (ansible formatted):

```yaml
    labels: 
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.backend={{ service_name }}"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAINNAME}; PathPrefixStrip: /{{ service_name }}"
        - "traefik.port={{ service_port }}"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
        - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true"
        - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds=315360000"
        - "traefik.frontend.headers.contentTypeNosniff=true"
        - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains=true"
```

So I want to use it like this:

```yaml
---
- hosts: nas
  vars:
    traefik_labels: list here
  tasks:
    - name: Run postgres container
      vars:
        service_name: "myService"
        service_port: "8080"
      docker_container:
        name: "service"
        image: "service:latest"
        state: "started"
        memory: 1G
        networks:
          - name: traefik_proxy
        env:
          POSTGRESQL_USER: username
          POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: "password"
        labels: "{{ traefik_labels }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite it is not documented, you can use a [vars lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html) to re-evaluate the templated variables:

```yaml
---
- name: "variables test"
  connection: local
  hosts: localhost
  become: no
  vars:
    list:
      - "service_name {{ service_name }}"
      - "service_port {{ service_port }}"
  tasks:
    - name: example task
      vars:
        service_name: "myService"
        service_port: "8080"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('vars', 'list') }}"
# You can even use the evaluated list inside a wit_items section:
    - name: example with items list on a templated var
      vars:
        service_name: "myService"
        service_port: "service port 8080"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ lookup('vars', 'list') }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [example task] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "service_name myService",
        "service_port 8080"
    ]
}

TASK [example with items list on a templated var] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=service_name myService) => {
    "msg": "service_name myService"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=service_port service port 8080) => {
    "msg": "service_port service port 8080"
}
```